Password vault web-app requiring multiple keys to reveal secrets
Thi is an existing product as I have seen it with my own eyes working. Unfortunately, I can not remember too much about it.
What its essence was: it has stored the secrets only in an encrypted form, encrypted by multiple keys. For example, there were 6 people in the group, then it could have been configured, that a cleartext secret (password) can be revealed only if 3 of them gives their key to do it. It could happen in a shared web session.
The fruits were very obvious: there was a common vault, but it was undecipherable even in the case of a successful security bleach. Beside that, induvidual guys, whose client laptop was hacked, or went rogue, could do nothing serious.
The cleartext password was not stored anywhere in the vault, only the public keys of the team and the encrypted forms of the secrets.
Probably it used some form of public key cryptography to do it.
It was very likely an open source tool.
I have seen a web app of it, possibly it might had also some client-side part, maybe not. At least a web frontend was used for the password revealing procedure.
